# Spring Boot publish REST & SOAP parallel

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, binding

I can't connect to my SOAP-Service listening on Port 9000 running a Spring-Boot application. The application is run in a docker container. The problem is that the soap-endpoint is listening on localhost instead of 0.0.0.0.

**I want to bind the soap services on 0.0.0.0:9000 not 127.0.0.1:9000. How can I accomplish this?**

Here my Setup:

```
Application.properties
soap.url = http://localhost:9000/
rest.url = http://localhost:9090/
server.port = 9090
```

Spring-boot starts up correctly

```
Springboot-Startup-log
2017-05-04 06:36:53.095  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http)
2017-05-04 06:36:53.110  INFO 1 --- [           main] ch.gemdat.Application                    : Started Application in 28.285 seconds (JVM running for 29.465)
2017-05-04 06:36:55.387  INFO 1 --- [           main] myapp                                    : - services/soap/form/call/v1
2017-05-04 06:36:55.388  INFO 1 --- [           main] myapp                                    : >> myapp successfully started in 0:31 <<
```

The tomcat (rest-services) started and listens to port 9090 default on interface 0.0.0.0. The soap-services are bound to localhost:9000.

```
netstat -tulpn
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
```

I perfectly can connect to all services running on port 9090. Because they are listening correctly on 0.0.0.0.

This is how I publish the soap-services:

```
private static void publishSoapServices() {
    MyAppLogger.info("Register soap endpoints...");
    BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefRegistry = new SimpleBeanDefinitionRegistry();
    ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner scanner = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(beanDefRegistry);
    scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(MyAppService.class));
    scanner.scan(Constants.SOAP_PACKAGE);

    for (String bean : beanDefRegistry.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        if (!bean.contains("springframework")) {
            try {
                Class<?> soapClass = Class.forName(beanDefRegistry.getBeanDefinition(bean).getBeanClassName());
                if (MyAppSoapService.class.isAssignableFrom(soapClass)) {
                    MyAppService soapService = (MyAppService) soapClass.newInstance();
                    Endpoint.publish(PropertyReader.getValue("soap.url") + soapService.getEndpoint(), soapService);
                    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(soapService);
                    MyAppLogger.info("- " + soapService.getEndpoint());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                MyAppLogger.error("Soap service ''{0}'' could not be published.", e, bean);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All services are available on localhost. Means `http://localhost:9000/services/soap/form/call/v1` works. But when I run it in a docker container (run-arguments: -p 9000:9000 -p 9090:9090) only the rest-services are available (because they only listen to localhost... and rest-services listens to all ips(0.0.0.0))

Docker inspect shows that the port is mapped correctly:

```
"Ports": {
            "9000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "9000"
                }
            ]
```

Comment: `Endpoint.publish(PropertyReader.getValue(http://localhost:9000/) + soapService.getEndpoint(), soapService);`  this is no valid Java code, and if you call this with _localhost:9000_ you are binding to localhost only

Comment: @P.J.Meisch thanks for your comment. You are correct. I wanted to make it easier to follow the code and replaced the `key` from the application.properties with the the value. But did it wrong. I corrected it to show the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I found the solution.

```
Application.properties
soap.url = http://0.0.0.0:9000/
rest.url = http://localhost:9090/
server.port = 9090
```

The solution is to set the `soap.url` used in the `application.properties` method to `http://0.0.0.0:9000/`. It doesn't work for `0.0.0.0:9000/` what I initially tried.

**Why does it work for the rest ports then?**
Well it doesn't. The rest-services work because the ports are not published under `rest.url` from the `application.properties`. They are bound to the initial spring-boot-app-port set by reading `server.port` from application.properties. The port got overridden by the tomcats default listening on the interface for `0.0.0.0`

As P.J.Meisch stated - it is simply the `soap.url` binding to `localhost` being the problem.

Comment: just wanted to answer that as well, that you need to bind bind the Endpoint to `http://0.0.0.0:9000/` instead of localhost. Glad you found it yourself ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to solve this for 2 days now. You get an additional upvote for this.